# Is there a more storage space efficient way to create this index on Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, storage

I’m using Postgres 9.5.4 on Linux 14.04.  I have created this index for my table

```
CREATE INDEX my_object_times_name_gin_trgm_idx 
ON my_object_times USING gin (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

so that I can run queries like this quickly …

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    "my_object_times" 
    INNER JOIN "my_objects" 
        ON "my_objects"."id" = "my_object_times"."my_object_id" 
    LEFT JOIN user_my_object_time_matches 
        ON my_object_times.id = user_my_object_time_matches.my_object_time_id
WHERE 
    (my_objects.user_id is null 
    AND my_object_times.name ilike 'DAVE ANTHONY')
```

My question is can I create the index in a different way such that the queries run quickly but I don’t use as much disk space?  I’m running really tight on disk space.

Comment: `ilike` without a wildcard is essentially the same as `upper(name) = 'DAVE ANTHONY'`. I think a simple btree index on `upper(name)` will be smaller then the GIN index and will support the same thing

Comment: The answer depends on what *"queries like this"* is supposed to mean *exactly*

Comment: By "like" I mean a query that returns the same results as the conditions defined in my question -- "(my_objects.user_id is null 
    AND my_object_times.name ilike 'DAVE ANTHONY')"

Comment: @Dave: Possible indexes depend on the range of possible query conditions. Always `ILIKE`? Always upper-case? No wildcards? Or always `ILIKE 'DAVE ANTHONY'`? What are possible values in `name `? Etc. Please clarify *in your question*.